Is the dimension of the largest Krylov subspace sensitive to the matrix in question?
Let $A$ denote a matrix and $b$ a vector. The order-$r$ Krylov subspace is defined as (See Wikipedia for more details)
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{K}_r(A,b)=\textrm{span}\{b, Ab, A^2b,\cdots, A^{r-1}b\}.
\end{eqnarray}
The largest dimension is defined as
\begin{eqnarray}
r_0=\textrm{dim}\textrm{span}\{b, Ab, A^2b,\cdots\}.
\end{eqnarray}
Clearly, the value of $r_0$ depends on $A$.
My question is that: Is the value of $r_0$ sensitive to the matrix $A$ in question? I mean when we change the matrix $A$ a litter bit, is it possible for $r_0$ to change a lot?
I think the answer is yes. If so, a further question is: Under what condition the value of $r_0$ is not sensitive to $A$?
Any comment to these questions are welcome. I am also grateful if you can provide some references related to these questions.
